# In Memory Caching with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I need to cache response of a function call and have an ability to refresh the cache with some parameter. I am using Spring Boot in memory cache-

```
@Cacheable("products")
public Product getProduct(AccountDetails account){
      return configProduct.getProduct(account.getId());
}
```

1. I am not able to pass key to the Cacheable annotation. I need to use ID as the key for this cache. How can i do that ?
2. In some of the examples , I do see cacheNames and key as valid values in that annotation. How ever i do get an error. I can only pass value in that annotation.
3. I am not getting the response from a DB call. However i am making a call to another jar file's method ( dependency added ) to get the response. I need a way to clear the cache also. Usually in examples i do see cacheEvict annotation with a method. But here technically i will be just refreshing the cache. How can i achieve that. Is there a way to put in the same method?

Please note that i am using Spring Boot 2.5.12 version

Thanks

---

Now i can get the cache initialized but Cacheable is not storing/returning anything. Call keeps going inside the method always. How can i test if cache has the value or even cacheable annotation stored the value in cache or not ?

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm not sure, but you can try to define key like `{#account.id}`
2. Be sure that you are using @Cacheable from `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable`. It has 'value' and 'key' properties.
3. I'm not exactly understand, what do you mean. But i think you should check the `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Caching` annotation. With this, you can define more than one cache annotation above one method.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @dezrhog . I am able to load the cache initial set up with a cache config. Do have 2 doubts further -  My understanding is that Cacheable annotation will store in cache as well and if it finds the value it will not call the method. But i dont see that happening while testing. It keeps on going inside same method. How do i know if cache has the value or not or if cacheable is even storing in cache or not.

Comment: @SajalSaxena You should always keep in mind proxying in Spring. Read about it. If you want to use a cached method from the same class in which it is defined, you need to call it from a self-autowired instance of this class - this is not the best solution, but it works. In runtime, you can view the stored cache by calling `applicationContext.getBean("cacheManager")` while debug. Don't forget to autowire `ApplicationContext`. If everything is done correctly, the method's response will be taken from the cache when it is called again with the same key

Comment: @SajalSaxena I also advise you to be careful with the use of caching. Because you need to be 100% sure of the consistency of the method response with the same key value. Otherwise, you can get various unpleasant errors in production